# Analyzing MODIS Aerosol Optical Depth

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp, modis

I want to extract AOD from the following hd5 file.  My objective is to have a tif file projected in EPSG:4326 with values of all 3 bands.

https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD19A2.006/2018.11.08/MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf

This is its corressponding xml file

https://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov/MOTA/MCD19A2.006/2018.11.08/MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf.xml

I used `gdalinfo` on the file.
It's output is

```
Driver: HDF4/Hierarchical Data Format Release 4
Files: MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf
Size is 512, 512
Coordinate System is `'
Metadata:
  ADDITIONALLAYERS=4
  ALGORITHMPACKAGEACCEPTANCEDATE=TBD
  ALGORITHMPACKAGEMATURITYCODE=Preliminary
  ALGORITHMPACKAGENAME=MOD_PR19
  ALGORITHMPACKAGEVERSION=2.0
  ASSOCIATEDINSTRUMENTSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  ASSOCIATEDINSTRUMENTSHORTNAME.2=MODIS
  ASSOCIATEDPLATFORMSHORTNAME.1=Terra
  ASSOCIATEDPLATFORMSHORTNAME.2=Aqua
  ASSOCIATEDSENSORSHORTNAME.1=MODIS
  ASSOCIATEDSENSORSHORTNAME.2=MODIS
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAG.1=Passed
  AUTOMATICQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION.1=output file is created and good
  CHARACTERISTICBINANGULARSIZE=30.0
  CHARACTERISTICBINSIZE=926.625433055556
  DATACOLUMNS=1200
  DATAROWS=1200
  DAYNIGHTFLAG=Day
  DESCRREVISION=6.1
  EASTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=80.83866018158
  EQUATORCROSSINGDATE.1=2018-11-08
  EQUATORCROSSINGLONGITUDE.1=79.0841246879515
  EQUATORCROSSINGTIME.1=05:14:00.440452
  EXCLUSIONGRINGFLAG.1=N
  GEOANYABNORMAL=False
  GEOESTMAXRMSERROR=50.0
  GLOBALGRIDCOLUMNS=43200
  GLOBALGRIDROWS=21600
  GRANULEBEGINNINGDATETIME=2018-11-08T05:05:00.000000Z, 2018-11-08T06:40:00.000000Z, 2018-11-08T06:45:00.000000Z
  GRANULEDAYNIGHTFLAG=Day, Day, Day
  GRANULEENDINGDATETIME=2018-11-08T05:10:00.000000Z, 2018-11-08T06:45:00.000000Z, 2018-11-08T06:50:00.000000Z
  GRANULENUMBERARRAY=63, 82, 83, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  GRANULEPOINTERARRAY=0, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  GRINGPOINTLATITUDE.1=19.9322184266328, 30.0331140824394, 29.9992886587456, 19.9001686194037
  GRINGPOINTLONGITUDE.1=63.6094781281049, 69.0252637066291, 80.8439676662222, 74.4928631354135
  GRINGPOINTSEQUENCENO.1=1, 2, 3, 4
  HDFEOSVersion=HDFEOS_V2.19
  HORIZONTALTILENUMBER=24
  identifier_product_doi=10.5067/MODIS/MCD19A2.006
  identifier_product_doi=10.5067/MODIS/MCD19A2.006
  identifier_product_doi_authority=http://dx.doi.org
  identifier_product_doi_authority=http://dx.doi.org
  INPUTPOINTER=MODMAIAC1km.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314035425.hdf, MODMAIAChkm.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314035439.hdf, MODMAIAC1kmGEO.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314035444.hdf, MYDMAIAC1km.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314033528.hdf, MYDMAIAChkm.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314033537.hdf, MYDMAIAC1kmGEO.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314033541.hdf
  LOCALGRANULEID=MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf
  LOCALVERSIONID=SCF V6.0.32
  LONGNAME=MODIS/Terra+Aqua Land Aerosol Optical Depth Daily L2G Global 1km SIN Grid
  MAXIMUMLINEINDEX=1562, 2029, 873, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  MAXIMUMOBSERVATIONS=5
  MAXIMUMSAMPLEINDEX=262, 1353, 1353, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  MINIMUMLINEINDEX=363, 1599, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  MINIMUMSAMPLEINDEX=0, 1198, 1116, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  NADIRDATARESOLUTION=1km
  NORTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=29.9999999973059
  NUMBEROFINPUTGRANULES=0
  NUMBEROFOVERLAPGRANULES=3
  ORBITNUMBER.1=100479
  ORBITNUMBERARRAY=100479, 100480, 100480, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1
  Orbit_amount=3
  Orbit_time_stamp=20183120505T  20183120645T  20183120815A  
  PARAMETERNAME.1=MODIS MAIAC file
  PGEVERSION=6.0.41
  PROCESSINGCENTER=GSFC
  PRODUCTIONDATETIME=2018-11-10T04:03:14.000Z
  QAPERCENTCLOUDCOVER.1=8
  QAPERCENTGOODQUALITY=56
  QAPERCENTINTERPOLATEDDATA.1=0
  QAPERCENTMISSINGDATA.1=0
  QAPERCENTOTHERQUALITY=36
  QAPERCENTOUTOFBOUNDSDATA.1=36
  RANGEBEGINNINGDATE=2018-11-08
  RANGEBEGINNINGTIME=05:05:00.000000
  RANGEENDINGDATE=2018-11-08
  RANGEENDINGTIME=06:50:00.000000
  REFERENCEORBITNUMBER=100479
  REPROCESSINGACTUAL=reprocessed
  REPROCESSINGPLANNED=further update is anticipated
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAG.1=Not Investigated
  SCIENCEQUALITYFLAGEXPLANATION.1=See http://landweb.nascom.nasa.gov/cgi-bin/QA_WWW/qaFlagPage.cgi?sat=Terra+Aqua&ver=C6 for the product Science Quality status.
  SHORTNAME=MCD19A2
  SOUTHBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=19.9999999982039
  SPSOPARAMETERS=END_OBJECT
  TileID=51024006
  TOTALADDITIONALOBSERVATIONS=1048973
  TOTALOBSERVATIONS=7537634
  VERSIONID=6
  VERTICALTILENUMBER=06
  WESTBOUNDINGCOORDINATE=63.8506663420923
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:Optical_Depth_047
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=[3x1200x1200] Optical_Depth_047 grid1km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:Optical_Depth_055
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=[3x1200x1200] Optical_Depth_055 grid1km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_3_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:AOD_Uncertainty
  SUBDATASET_3_DESC=[3x1200x1200] AOD_Uncertainty grid1km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_4_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:FineModeFraction
  SUBDATASET_4_DESC=[3x1200x1200] FineModeFraction grid1km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_5_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:Column_WV
  SUBDATASET_5_DESC=[3x1200x1200] Column_WV grid1km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_6_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:AOD_QA
  SUBDATASET_6_DESC=[3x1200x1200] AOD_QA grid1km (16-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_7_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:AOD_MODEL
  SUBDATASET_7_DESC=[3x1200x1200] AOD_MODEL grid1km (8-bit unsigned integer)
  SUBDATASET_8_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:Injection_Height
  SUBDATASET_8_DESC=[3x1200x1200] Injection_Height grid1km (32-bit floating-point)
  SUBDATASET_9_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid5km:cosSZA
  SUBDATASET_9_DESC=[3x240x240] cosSZA grid5km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_10_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid5km:cosVZA
  SUBDATASET_10_DESC=[3x240x240] cosVZA grid5km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_11_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid5km:RelAZ
  SUBDATASET_11_DESC=[3x240x240] RelAZ grid5km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_12_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid5km:Scattering_Angle
  SUBDATASET_12_DESC=[3x240x240] Scattering_Angle grid5km (16-bit integer)
  SUBDATASET_13_NAME=HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid5km:Glint_Angle
  SUBDATASET_13_DESC=[3x240x240] Glint_Angle grid5km (16-bit integer)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  512.0)
Upper Right (  512.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  512.0,  512.0)
Center      (  256.0,  256.0)
```

I want to get a GeoTiff projected in EPSG:4326.

I tried using 
`gdalwarp -t_srs "EPSG:4326" HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314.hdf":grid1km:
Optical_Depth_055 test.tif`

This gave me a tif file which i then visualized in QGIS. You will see a small greenish tint. It looks like the tile has minimized in size.

[image]

On checking out the layer properties :

[image]

How do i know if the raster is projected as it should have been?

Because when I change the layer properties to the following (Notice setting red band to Band 2)

[image]

I get this :

[image]

When I use `SingleBand Pseudo Colour` for raster rendering :

[image]

I get this :

[image]

Can anyone explain what is going on and why the Raster expands on changing the RGB bands as any of the AOD Bands?

Answer (score 2):

Note the difference between **band rendering** done by QGIS and the actual **raster extent** and **values**. The values of your raster remain the same, regardless of the band rendering (Multicolor band, Singleband gray, Paletted unique/values) you select in Layer properties.

If you take your original layer (i.e. HDF4_EOS:EOS_GRID:"MCD19A2.A2018312.h24v06.006.2018314040314":grid1km:Optical_Depth_055) and change it to *Singleband gray*, it will show you that the raster expands beyond the initial 'triangle' you see in the beginning:

[image]

The reason for this is that the default value stretching for Singleband gray is to show *all* values, from min to maximum using a grayband scale.  Have a look here for further options on displaying the raster the way you want:

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#band-rendering

Just keep in mind that whatever you choose here doesn't change the raster values. Regarding the projection, GDAL warp is the correct tool to use for reprojecting.